# sessions handling in rails when signed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

When I log in I get sessions working, I can log out etc. But when I create an account I can't do that, the link to logging out is not there. Any suggestions?

Here is the code for logging out layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Auth</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<!--Detta kod säger bara när du loggar in ska man kunna se länkarna... du måste skriva om den så att den säger bara
när du är inloggad ELLER skapat konto visa dessa länkar-->
<div id="user_nav">
  <% if current_user %>
    Logged in as <%= current_user.email %> DETTA ÄR APPLICATION.HTML.ERB.
    <%= link_to "Log out", log_out_path %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", sign_up_path %> or
    <%= link_to "log in", log_in_path %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
<% end %>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  #auth
  #behöver new defineras? ska den vara tom? varför måste den finnas? ny session? 
  #är det korrekt att skriva params[:blabla] etc?
  #varför kickar sessions in bara när man loggar in? och inte när man skapat konto?

def new
end

  #det känns som sessions skapas bara när man loggar in.. AKA AUTHENTICATE
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to testsida_url, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
end

end
```

Here is users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to testsida_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

   def update
     if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

Here is application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def authorize
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" if current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

So I dont really know why sessions is not working when creating accounts, but when logging in they work? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new `user`, you aren't creating a new `session` as well (or at the very least it doesn't appear like you are). The easiest fix would be to set your `:user_id` session variable when a new user is created.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # new

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # Set the current user id below
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to testsida_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  # user_params
end
```

Comment: Yep you need to set the id in the session on sign in and on create.

Comment: It's the line under the comment in my code: `session[:user_id] = user.id`.

Comment: Yes i added that line sessions[:user... in my user controller, but now i get this error "undefined local variable or method `user' "

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I mistyped the variable name. It should be `@user`, not `user`. Try that. I also updated my answer.

Comment: That worked exactly as I wanted, now sessions seem to work when i create and log in.. one last question.. is this approach safe when handling users?

Comment: It should be... I'm certainly no expert when it comes to security, and I've never rolled my authentication system before. I use the [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Comment: Ok thank you so much man :), is there any way I can keep in contact with you, not for questions but if u ever interested in discussing rails in theory? do u have skype?